# reduce the size of a string

Tags: c, string, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

(disclaimer: this is not a complete exercise because I have to finish it, but error occurred in this part of code)

I did this exercise to practice memory allocation.

> create a function that takes an url (a C string) and returns the name of the website (with "www." and with the extension).
> for example, given wikipedia's link, "http://www.wikipedia.org/", it has to return only "www.wikipedia.org" in another string (dynamically allocated in the heap).

this is what I did so far:
do a for-loop, and when "i" is greater than 6, then start copying each character in another string until "/" is reached.
I need to allocate the other string, and then reallocate that.

here's my attempt so far:

```
char *read_website(const char *url) {
    char *str = malloc(sizeof(char)); 
    if (str == NULL) {
        exit(1); 
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; url[i] != "/" && i > 6; ++i) {
        if (i <= 6) {
            continue; 
        }
        char* s = realloc(str, sizeof(char) + 1); 
        if (s == NULL) {
            exit(1); 
        }
        *str = *s; 
    }
    return str; 
}

int main(void) {
    char s[] = "http://www.wikipedia.org/"; 
    char *str = read_website(s); 
    return 0; 
}
```

(1) by debugging line-by-line, I've noticed that the program ends once for-loop is reached.

(2) another thing: I've chosen to create another pointer when I've used `realloc`, because I have to check if there's memory leak. Is it a good practice? Or should I've done something else?

Comment: That's because your for loop doesn't do anything. Go back and make sure you understand what `continue` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `url[i] != "/"` is incorrect, it is a type mismatch. You should compare the character `url[i]` with a character constant `'/'`, not a string literal `"/"`.
- `char *s = realloc(str, sizeof(char) + 1);` reallocates only to size 2, not the current length plus 1.
- you do not increase the pointers, neither do you use the index variable.
- instead of using `malloc` and `realloc`, you should first compute the length of the server name and allocate the array with the correct size directly.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *read_website(const char *url) {
    // skip the protocol part
    if (!strncmp(url, "http://", 7))
        url += 7;
    else if (!strncmp(url, "https://", 8))
        url += 8;
    // compute the length of the domain name, stop at ':' or '/'
    size_t n = strcspn(url, "/:");
    // return an allocated copy of the substring
    return strndup(url, n);
}

int main(void) {
    char s[] = "http://www.wikipedia.org/"; 
    char *str = read_website(s);
    printf("%s -> %s\n", s, str);
    free(str);
    return 0; 
}
```

`strndup()` is a POSIX function available on many systems and that will be part of the next version of the C Standard. If it is not available on your target, here is a simple implementation:

```
char *strndup(const char *s, size_t n) {
    char *p;
    size_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < n && s[i]; i++)
        continue;
    p = malloc(i + 1);
    if (p) {
        memcpy(p, s, i);
        p[i] = '\0';
    }
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment doesn't say the returned string must be of minimal size, and the amount of memory used for URLs is minimal.

Building on [chqrlie](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70405680/451601)'s solution, I'd start by finding the beginning of the domain name (skipping the protocol portion), duplicate the rest of the string, and then truncate the result.  Roughly:

```
char *prot[] = { "http://", "https://" };
for( int i=0; i < 2; i++ ) {
  if( 0 == strncmp(url, http, strlen(prot)) ) 
     s += strlen(prot);
     break;
  }
}
char *output = strdup(s);
if( output ) {
  size_t n = strcspn(output, "/:");
  output[n] = '\0';
}
return output;
```

The returned pointer can still be freed by the caller, so the total "wasted" space is limited to the trailing part of the truncated URL.

Comment: Simple implementation with a generic approach for the protocol part, but duplicating the whole string seems wasteful. why not just `return strndup(s, strcspn(output, "/:"));` ?  The assignment does not specify the return string should be have minimal allocation, but the OP's implementation attemts to achieve that by reallocating the string one byte at a time up to the end of the domain name...

Comment: Unless the memory used by the application is very constrained, literally measured in bytes, then to me the trailing duplicated string is less important than the portability constraint of strndup. I'm not saying you're wrong, only that it's a judgement call.

Comment: Makes sense... Then you might steer away from `strdup` altogether and  use `malloc(n + 1)` and `memcpy()` :)